# Core Data - Access the sqlite file created by simulator?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data

Is it possible to access the sqlite filr for core data, and run queries against it?
Where is this file located at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file will be located under the iPhone Simulator in your Application Support directory.

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator
```

From there you will see several directories corresponding to the simulator versions.  Under the version directory will be an Applications directory and then a GUID directory.  One of those GUID directories will be your application.  From there your sqlite file should be in the Documents directory and you can play with it from the command line tool `sqlite3`.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer a graphical interface to analyze and query your database. It allows you to see clearly how Xcode/CoreData is naming the data fields. For example, I use the "SQLite Manager" add-on for the Firefox browser.